# How did the number of elements in each array end up being less than they were in their parent array (array of arrays)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

This problems seems to go away when I dont use **shuffle(train_data)**. I also tried doing **shuffle(train_data_1)** and **shuffle(train_data_2)** seperately but in that case too, the distribution seems to change.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from random import shuffle

train_data_1 = np.load('training_data_v1.npy', allow_pickle=True)
train_data_2 = np.load('training_data_v2.npy', allow_pickle=True)

train_data = np.vstack((train_data_1, train_data_2))

df = pd.DataFrame(train_data)
print(df.head())
print(Counter(df[1].apply(str)))
```

```
Output :
                                                 0          1
0  [[33, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, ...  [0, 1, 0]
1  [[33, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, ...  [0, 1, 0]
2  [[33, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, ...  [0, 1, 0]
3  [[33, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, ...  [0, 1, 0]
4  [[33, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, ...  [0, 1, 0]
Counter({'[0, 1, 0]': 6064, '[1, 0, 0]': 542, '[0, 0, 1]': 394})
```

**Seperating the forwards, lefts and rights into their respective arrays**

```
shuffle(train_data)
```

```
lefts = []
rights = []
forwards = []

for data in train_data:
    img = data[0]
    choice = data[1]

    if choice == [1,0,0]:
        lefts.append([img,choice])
    elif choice == [0,1,0]:
        forwards.append([img,choice])
    elif choice == [0,0,1]:
        rights.append([img,choice])
    else:
        print('no matches')

print (len(forwards), len(lefts), len(rights))
```

```
Output:
6086 763 151
```

At start, the distribution of forward, left, right was (6064, 542, 394)

Now, it is (6096, 763, 151)

**How has the distribution changed??**

What am I doing wrong!?

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing without seeing train_data. Are you 100% certain train_data is exactly the same as the created df, In any case, maybe look to build your forward, left, and right from the df and not train_data. iterrows() is one method to look at that is similar to what you have tried.

Comment: No that isnt a problem here. random.shuffle() seems to be the issue

Comment: Please post an MCVE. Something I can reproduce. I don't believe your assessment about shuffle being the issue, but I can't test it with what you've provided.

Comment: I used shuffle after seperating into forward,left,right. Now there isn't any problem and the data is saved in correct distribution

Answer (score 0):

Dont use shuffle(train_data) instead after the formation of forwards, lefts and rights array, use shuffle() on them individually.

```
shuffle(forwards)
shuffle(lefts)
shuffle(rights)
```

Now there isn't any problem with the distribution and shuffling is also performed correctly.